# Getting an empty array from zustand store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, zustand

I am trying get the fetched array from the zustand store, but it's returned as empty.

`script.jsx`

```
const store = Zstore();

const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    store.fetchStock(params.id);
}, []);


console.log(store.stock); // Empty array
```

`Zstore.js`

```
import { create } from 'zustand';
import axios from 'axios';

const Zstore = create((set) => ({
    stock: [],

    fetchStock: async (id) => {
    
        const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/searchList/')
        const stock = res.data.filter((stock) => stock.symbol == id.toUpperCase()).map((stock) => {
            return {
                symbol: stock.symbol,
                name: stock.name,
            }
        });
        set({stock});
                console.log(stock); // Array not empty
    },
}));

export default Zstore;
```

I did attempt to add `store.stock.length` as a dependency to the `useEffect` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your component is not rerendering due to state changes,
try to update your component this way,
Your store selection should look like this const `stock = Zstore(state => state.stock);`

```
  const params = useParams();
  const stock = Zstore(state => state.stock);

  useEffect(() => {
    Zstore.getState().fetchStock(params.id);
  }, [params.id]);

  // This will re-render the component when `stock` changes, displaying the updated data.
  console.log(stock);
```